# Customising Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a Django site on which users can make bookings for events.

I need to create a backend site for internal management staff to create events, manage events and bookings, do all sorts of other stuff.

Would I be better off customising the Django admin site for the backend (it is going to be MUCH more complicated than listing instances of models, updating individual ones, adding new ones etc.) or just creating my own backend for it from scratch?

My instinct is that, since I'm not going to be using any of the standard functionality of the existing Django admin, I'd be better off making my own and keeping the old Django admin for site admins to use but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when creating a proper backend for management, like Magento etc., I prefer to create a whole new web app for it.

It allows for more freedom around designing the interface, especially something based on AJAX.

I am not sure how much you can customize the Django admin templates, but I am positive it is very difficult, if not impossible to implement stuff like widgets, analytics etc.

However that being said, for most of my applications I simply use Django admin, as it offers most of the required features including custom forms.

So here is my advice, if you require to implement fine tuned UX and/or have very complex forms which you can't use with Django admin. Then go ahead and create your own admin panel.

Go through the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin) and [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) once to decide which to use.

Also checkout [django-admin-tools](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

> **Note**: Please correct me if I am wrong, post some links showing
>   examples of complex admin panel implemented using Django admin.

Comment: When you say "I prefer to create a whole new web app for it", do you mean an entirely new site hosted at a new URL? So something like the main site being on example.com but the management site on manage.example.com?

Comment: Always separate the logical segments of your website using Django applications. That way, you have the freedom to implement it in either of the ways you mentioned.

Comment: So I've got an app called "people" which deals with all aspects of users. That app has a load of views for the main front-end of the website and a load of views for the back-end management site. Surely you're not suggesting I move the management functionality into it's own app? If it's all dealing with user stuff, it should all go in the same app, no?

Comment: Depends on your project set up. I generally separate application logic and views in my Django projects. That is, I have apps that will implement the logic- models, and functions to interact with them. Signals etc. I have other apps which contain views for different segments of the website. Something like `app/` for all apps without views, `web/` contains the applications with views.

This is entirely my own personal organization structure, helps me modularize the code.